# iPhone SDK: Populate Table View From Core Data

Tags: iphone, uitableview, core-data

I am looking for a tutorial that shows how to populate a UITableView from core data, allowing to add records and delete them.

There are a few projects that I have found, but they are hard to follow without the steps to build them.

Anyone seen tutorials on this?  Or better yet, videos?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you looked at `NSFetchedResultsController`? It takes a fetch request and is designed to be used directly within your `UITableViewDataSource`, doing much of the heavy lifting.

Handling inserts, deletes and updates is supported but requires a bit more work. Jeff LaMarche has some great articles on `NSFetchedResultsController`.

http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/search/label/Core%20Data

Answer (score 0):

This one was helpful for me:
[core-data-getting-started](http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-tutorial-getting-started)

This one from apple with detailed explanation + code source
[core data tutorial for iPhone OS](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/iPhoneCoreData01/Articles/A1_NextSteps.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008305-CH101-SW5)