# How to Display data from SQlite & core-data into multi table views in xcode 4.3?

Tags: iphone, xcode, sqlite, core-data, ios5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iPhone SDK: Populate Table View From Core Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2806040/iphone-sdk-populate-table-view-from-core-data)

is there any good tutorial shows how to display data from SQlite into multi table view using xcode 4.2 or 4.3 with core data and story board??

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

For Sqlite and tableview. I suggest you go through following tutorial and it's also contain sample code..

[SQlite tutorial for iOS Developer](http://dblog.com.au/iphone-development-tutorials/iphone-sdk-tutorial-reading-data-from-a-sqlite-database/)

**[another working demo and sample code also available..](http://www.icodeblog.com/2008/08/19/iphone-programming-tutorial-creating-a-todo-list-using-sqlite-part-1/)**

Comment: Thx Nit, this tutorial looks great but i dont know if it will work with xcode 4.3, anyway ill follow that and see what will happen, cheers.

Comment: If it helped you than accept the answer..it will help you lot...

Comment: will do, but if not!  :)

Comment: I have xcode 4.3.2 when I run it shows lots of errors! spent very long time trying to fix it but no luck!

Comment: I have added another tutorial reference...and it's contain working demo...

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this question and answers

[iPhone SDK: Populate Table View From Core Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2806040/iphone-sdk-populate-table-view-from-core-data)

Also, CS193P Lecture on this subject are great

Answer (score 0):

You can find many tutrial getting data in TableView but for multipletable view mean you can follow the technique as the tutorial describes for single table.

Tutorial

http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Example_SQLite_based_iPhone_Application

hope this helps